# Encoding and Serialization Code Gives Different Result C# and Python

Tags: python, c#, serialization, encoding, base64

I tried to convert this C# code (encoding and serialization) to Python but results are different. Why?

```
    var dictt = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "aaa", "6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==" },
        { "bbb", "4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI="},
    };

    JavaScriptSerializer serialzr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                       
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialzr.Serialize(dictt))); //eyJpdiI6IjZtakR4M0N5YTRKdmJUTE1lblBwWEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNFU1TStWMnlvSUE3cldqNDZyZGhUQmdwRWpmMXpZSzBtMTFsRE03RFJDST0ifQ==
```

```py
dictt = {
    "aaa": "6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==",
    "bbb": "4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI="
    }
     
    y = json.dumps(dictt)
    #y= {"aaa": "6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==", "bbb": "4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI="}
    json_object = json.loads(y) #convert it to json, like serialize in C#
    # json_object = {'aaa': '6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==', 'bbb': '4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI='} 
    json_object_utf8_encoded = str(json_object).encode('utf8') #encode utf8
    #json_object_utf8_encoded = b"{'aaa': '6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==', 'bbb': '4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI='}"
    json_base64 = base64.b64encode(json_object_utf8_encoded) #convert to base64 string      
    #json_base64 = "b'eydpdic6ICc2bWpEeDNDeWE0SnZiVExNZW5QcFhBPT0nLCAndmFsdWUnOiAnNFU1TStWMnlvSUE3cldqNDZyZGhUQmdwRWpmMXpZSzBtMTFsRE03RFJDST0nfQ=='"
    json_base64_str = json_base64.decode("utf-8") 
    return json_base64_str 
    #eydpdic6ICc2bWpEeDNDeWE0SnZiVExNZW5QcFhBPT0nLCAndmFsdWUnOiAnNFU1TStWMnlvSUE3cldqNDZyZGhUQmdwRWpmMXpZSzBtMTFsRE03RFJDST0nfQ==
```

Comment: Might be easier if you just looked the non-base64 form to see the difference

Comment: I added all values in comments @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small difference between the following two python commands, resulting with two different outputs: `"` vs. `'`.

While this one:

```
serialized = json.dumps(dict)
print(serialized)
```

outputs:

```
{"aaa": "6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==", "bbb": "4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI="}
```

This one:

```
serialized = json.dumps(dict)
deserialized = json.loads(serialized)
print(str(deserialized))
```

outputs:

```
{'aaa': '6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==', 'bbb': '4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI='}
```

You work with the latter one: you're unnecessarily deserializing the json, and then calling `str` upon it, giving you the different result. Just drop the `json.loads` step.

EDIT:

The returned values (C# vs python) will still not match, because C# serializer (whether it's `JavaScriptSerializer` or the more common `JsonConvert.Serialize` of Newtonsoft) outputs a json with no spaces:

```
{"aaa":"6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==","bbb":"4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI="}
```

while python's `json.dumps` outputs a json with spaces:

```
{"aaa": "6mjDx3Cya4JvbTLMenPpXA==", "bbb": "4U5M+V2yoIA7rWj46rdhTBgpEjf1zYK0m11lDM7DRCI="}
```

Even if you'd pass an indentation argument to `json.dumps` (e.g., `json.dumps(dict, indent=2)`), you can't do that with `JavaScriptSerializer`, and although you could do it with Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert.Serialize` it would still not work, since the latter uses CRLF characters for the indentation, while python doesn't.

That being said, it shouldn't matter, because the logical output is the same: A Base64 encoding of the serialized dictionary.

Comment: I removed `json.loads` step and str convertion in `json_object_utf8_encoded = str(json_object).encode('utf8')` line. But new result is `eyJpdiI6ICI2bWpEeDNDeWE0SnZiVExNZW5QcFhBPT0iLCAidmFsdWUiOiAiNFU1TStWMnlvSUE3cldqNDZyZGhUQmdwRWpmMXpZSzBtMTFsRE03RFJDST0ifQ==` . It's still not same.

Comment: I want literally same results because after I generate python result, I will send this result as parameter to c# method and c# code will decripte it. ( and I can't change c# method. ) Is there any way of that?

Comment: *"And c# code will decrypt it"* - what do you mean by "decrypt"? If by that you mean that it will decode it from Base64 and then deserialize it to dictionary, then it will work fine.